# iptables static routing simple entry (ddwrt)

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, dd-wrt

Im trying to add a policy-based routing entry to my dd-wrt router, the router is in Router mode, not Gateway mode (using my own Ipv4 block)

bsaically I wish to redirect  traffic to a different gateway on the local subnet..
example i want 8.8.8.8 to go out on SECONDIP .  for the LAN clients (they have their own public ip)

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 8.8.8.8 -o secondip'

thank you in advance